# Address header on every page in komacv

Tags: cv

I am writing a cv with the komacv package and I want to have an address header on the top of every page, except the first page. How can I do that?

Edit: Here a working example with the solution:

```
\documentclass[%
]{komacv}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\clearpairofpagestyles

\ifoot{CV~\firstname~\familyname}
\ofoot{\pagemark/\totalpagemark}

\ihead{\ifnum \value{page}=1\else My Address Header Left Entry\fi}
\ohead{\ifnum \value{page}=1\else My Address Header Right Entry\fi}

\addtokomafont{firstnamefont}{\fontsize{35}{50}}

\renewcommand*{\title}{CV}% PDF metadata
\renewcommand*{\firstname}{Jane}
\renewcommand*{\familyname}{Eyre}
\renewcommand*{\acadtitle}{B.\,Ed.}
\renewcommand*{\addressstreet}{Ferndean House}
\renewcommand*{\addresscity}{Ferndean Village}
\renewcommand*{\address}[2]{\addressstreet{#1}\addresscity{#2}}
\renewcommand*{\mobile}{009-87654321}


\begin{document}
\raggedbottom

\maketitle

\section{Personal Information}
\cvitem{Date of birth}{February 15, 1828}

\newpage

\section{Education}
\cventry{1835--1838}{Homeschooling}{}{Gateshead}{grades 1--3}{Teacher: Mr.~NN, under supervision of my aunt Ms. Reed.}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunaly there is no MWE in the question, so the following answer is only a guess.

Current version of `komacv` loads package `scrlayer-scrpage`. Therefore you can use something like

```
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\ifnum \value{page}=1\else My Address Header Entry\fi}
```